# Not able to remove link from add/remove Program

Tags: nsis

I created an window application for which I need to create setup.For creating setup i am using NSIS. I had written script to create setup file I need to link this setup file to Add/remove program. For add link to add/remove program I am using following code:

```
 WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\appName" "DisplayName" "Name"
 WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\appName" "AppName" '"$INSTDIR\UninstallApp.exe"'
```

To delete the link from add/Remove program I am using following code :

```
 DeleteRegKey HKCU "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\appName"
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Do you have "RequestExecutionLevel user" in your script?

Comment: Yes I am using **"RequestExecutionLevel user"**.I am not able to delete the uninstaller.exe file which is linking to "Name" in add/remove program.Can you tell me how to write code to self delete.

Comment: Is this a 64 bit machine? Please post your real code, "appName" should not be your key and "AppName" is not a valid value, you probably mean UninstallString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the fact that "AppName" is wrong and should be "UninstallString" it looks like the code should work.

You should inspect it with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and see why the delete fails. My only guess at this point is that your real code has a typo...